# WinAppDriver: how to obtain a list of children to a ListView control

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation, appium, winappdriver

New to UI automation, using Appium WinAppDriver on a UWP app, i am trying to find a way to get a list of all the elements in a particular `ListView` control, and then get values form each. I am maybe wrong, but there appears to be a child/parent relationship between some `WindowElement`, which can be seen when examining an particular screen in inspect tool.  Please consider below simplified piece of code:

```
WindowElement x = session.FindElementsByClassName("ListView").ToList()[1];
List<WindowElement> y = x.FindElementsByClassName("ListViewItem").ToList();
foreach(WindowElement z in y)
{
     string name = z.FindElementByName("itemName").Text;
     string id = z.FindElementByName("itemID").Text;
}
```

1. Is this a correct approach in general, or am i missing something fundamental about this? I want to get a list of all of the items from a ListView
2. This statement: `List<WindowElement> y = x.FindElementsByClassName("ListViewItem").ToList();` gives me an error because `FindElementsByClassName()` apparently returns a list of `AppiumWebElement` and not `WindowElement`

Comment: AFAIK this is how the WinAppDriver works, only you do not need to call `ToList()` since FindElementsByClassName("ListViewItem") should give you an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
List<WindowElement> y = x.FindElementsByClassName("ListViewItem").ToList();
```

Try this and see if it works

```
var y = x.FindElementsByClassName("ListViewItem");
foreach (var z in y)
{
 string name = z.FindElementByName("itemName").Text;
 string id = z.FindElementByName("itemID").Text;
}
```

For my test cases, FindElements only works on the driver and not on the Element. and it always returns Ilist

Answer (score 0):

Question is asked a long time ago, but anyway:

1. It is possible approach, but you better avoid finding elements by ClassName, especially by concrete index `[1]`, if you classes are not unique and in future there could be added more same controls results will became wrong. Better to use unique AutomationId-s for elements if it is possible, and find elements `ById`, `ByAccessibilityId`, `ByName` and so on.
2. Yes. When you are trying to get elements from WindowElement you will get AppiumWebElement. You can use it. Otherwise if you wand to get Windows element - you shoud search elements in session, as in your code beginning.